# Find region's bounding box using leptonica

Tags: c, image, image-processing, computer-vision

I'm trying to find bounding boxes of continuous regions of black pixels that intersect with the area between blue and red lines (see image below).

I've used leptonica library for really simple image processing and I know how to approach the problem "by hand". However, I think that leptonica already has fast tools for that job - the problem is that it's not very well documented and I don't know which functions should I look for.

I'd be grateful for some hints and pointers to functions in leptonica's doc.

Here's the example image:

[image: Example]

The green box is what I need to find for all of the islands in the area between lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution:

Given that `PIX* pixb` is a 1bpp source image and `BOX* b` is the box between red and blue lines:

```
BOXA* bb = pixConnCompBB(pixb, 8); // to find bounding boxes of all connected components      on the image
BOXA* bil = boxaIntersectsBox(bb, b);
```

The result is an array `bil` of bounding boxes that intersect the area between lines.